# XSLT: How to place multiple level nodes in <ol> in place of xls:number format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to xsl and messing about with a sample template to try and figure things out.
I managed to get this far as per below snippets. Not sure if the way I'm applying the template for the different System.AreaPath is correct, but seems to work?

The one thing I'm struggling with right now is to use ol (or ol for Epic, ul for all siblings) and css, instead of the template sample putting every in a div and h{$level}.

I'm hoping this will also resolve the current issue of the number format - apply-template does not reset the count when applied twice as I have done here.

Any suggestions or samples will be appreciated as I'm not finding - or rather understanding correctly how to implement - the various search results and samples I have found. (for-each and when came up frequently)

I hope the above makes sense and that the code pasted is sufficient?
Thanks in advance!
 - Jacques

xml: (edit: xml, not xlm)

```
<result executedDate="8/8/2017" executedBy="abc" email="abc@email.com">
<columns>
<System.Id name="ID" width="75" type="Integer"/>
<System.WorkItemType name="Work Item Type" width="75" type="String"/>
<System.Title name="Title" width="150" type="String"/>
<System.AreaPath name="Area Path" width="75" type="TreePath"/>
</columns>
<options>
 ...
</options>
<workitem id="1051" type="Epic" state="In Progress">
<System.Id>1051</System.Id>
<System.WorkItemType>Epic</System.WorkItemType>
<System.Title>Epic1</System.Title>
<System.AreaPath>Path1</System.AreaPath>
<workitem id="5411" type="Feature" state="Done">
  <System.Id>5411</System.Id>
  <System.WorkItemType>Feature</System.WorkItemType>
  <System.Title>Feature1</System.Title>
  <System.AreaPath>Path1</System.AreaPath>
  <workitem id="5414" type="Product Backlog Item" state="Done">
    <System.Id>5414</System.Id>
    <System.WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</System.WorkItemType>
    <System.Title>Backlog Item 1</System.Title>
    <System.AreaPath>Path1</System.AreaPath>
  </workitem>
  <workitem id="5418" type="Product Backlog Item" state="Done">
    <System.Id>5418</System.Id>
    <System.WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</System.WorkItemType>
    <System.Title>Backlog Item 2</System.Title>
    <System.AreaPath>Path1</System.AreaPath>
  </workitem>
 </workitem>
</workitem>
<workitem id="1529" type="Epic" state="In Progress">
<System.Id>1529</System.Id>
<System.WorkItemType>Epic</System.WorkItemType>
<System.Title>Epic 2</System.Title>
<System.AreaPath>Path2</System.AreaPath>
<workitem id="3956" type="Feature" state="Done">
  <System.Id>3956</System.Id>
  <System.WorkItemType>Feature</System.WorkItemType>
  <System.Title>Feature 2</System.Title>
  <System.AreaPath>Path 2</System.AreaPath>
  <workitem id="5955" type="Product Backlog Item" state="Done">
    <System.Id>5955</System.Id>
    <System.WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</System.WorkItemType>
    <System.Title>Backlog item 3</System.Title>
    <System.AreaPath>Path2</System.AreaPath>
  </workitem>
  <workitem id="6667" type="Product Backlog Item" state="Done">
    <System.Id>6667</System.Id>
    <System.WorkItemType>Product Backlog Item</System.WorkItemType>
    <System.Title>Backlog item 4</System.Title>
    <System.AreaPath>Path2</System.AreaPath>
  </workitem>
</workitem>
```

xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/result /workitem[@type != 'Bug' and System.AreaPath='Path2']"/>
            <p/>
            <h2>Section 2</h2>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/result /workitem[@type != 'Bug' and System.AreaPath='Path1']"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//workitem">
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="count(ancestor-or-self::*) "/>
    <xsl:element name="h{$level}">
        <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="System.Title"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <div style="margin-left:15px;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

html ouput:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   <h2>Section 1</h2>
   <h2>2. Epic 2</h2>
   <div style="margin-left:15px;">
     <h3>2.1. Feature 2</h3>
       <div style="margin-left:15px;">
       <h4>2.1.1. Backlog item 3</h4>
       <div style="margin-left:15px;"></div>
       <h4>2.1.2. Backlog item 4</h4>
       <div style="margin-left:15px;"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
<p></p>
<h2>Section 2</h2>
<h2>1. Epic1</h2>
<div style="margin-left:15px;">
  <h3>1.1. Feature1</h3>
  <div style="margin-left:15px;">
    <h4>1.1.1. Backlog item 1</h4>
    <div style="margin-left:15px;"></div>
    <h4>1.1.2. Backlog item 2</h4>
    <div style="margin-left:15px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired html output:
This is basesd on a current view in use that I'm trying to replicate. Might opt to not use the table later on, but the `<ul>` layout is what I'm after.

Also, the 'epic' node will likely not be used and can be excluded in the query generating the xml

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class=class1>Section 1</td> <!-- list all features from Path2 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class=class2>
                <li>Feature 3
                    <ul>
                        <li>Backlog item 5</li>
                        <li>Backlog item 6</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Feature 4
                    <ul>
                        <li>Backlog item 7</li>
                        <li>Backlog item 8</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class=class1>Section 2</td>  <!-- list all features from Path1 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul class=class2>
                <li>Feature1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Backlog item 1</li>
                        <li>Backlog item 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Feature 2
                    <ul>
                        <li>Backlog item 3</li>
                        <li>Backlog item 4</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would help if you could post the desired XML output.

Comment: Still trying to figure this out so not sure what the desired XML should be?
Added the html of an existing view I'm trying to replicate as a start.

Comment: You want to have a list inside a table cell?

Comment: I want to get away from the table cell. This is unfortunately how the existing page is setup (lots of tables/nested tables) that I'm trying to replicate. The ul is what I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected output is not clear. If you want a nested list, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/result">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem[@type != 'Bug' and starts-with(System.AreaPath, 'Path')]"/>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="workitem">
    <li>
        <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1. "/>
        <xsl:value-of select="System.Title"/>
    </li>
    <xsl:if test="workitem">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="workitem"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and get:

**Result**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>1. Epic1</li>
      <ul>
        <li>1.1. Feature1</li>
        <ul>
          <li>1.1.1. Backlog Item 1</li>
          <li>1.1.2. Backlog Item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li>2. Epic 2</li>
      <ul>
        <li>2.1. Feature 2</li>
        <ul>
          <li>2.1.1. Backlog item 3</li>
          <li>2.1.2. Backlog item 4</li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot to get me going